# Debería preocuparme de la clase Looper?

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo debug de mi app, pero hay una parte en el que parece haber problema, en la clase **Looper.class**

```
public static void loop() {
throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");}
```

y

```
public void quit() {
throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");}
```

Estos dos metodos se ejecutan como diez veces, quisiera saber si es un problema del cual deba preocuparme, esta classe es propia del sistema de android studio

Comment: Cuando decis que "parece haber un problema" es porque hay un problema y se corta la ejecución o porque notas que hay un posible lanzamiento de excepcion?

Answer (score 0):

**Looper** no es una clase de *android studio*, es más bien una clase nativa de [*Android*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper) que también incorpora [*Kotlin*](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Looper). Es común que veas que el ciclo de ejecución en modo *debug* pase muchas veces por dicha clase ya que la misma permite que las tareas se ejecuten de forma secuencial en un solo hilo.

Si deberías preocuparte o no depende de si estas utilizando *Looper* para un propósito particular (y en ese caso si deberías manejar la posible excepción) o si es solamente parte del ciclo de vida de tu app (el hilo principal de Android esta construido con `Looper` y `Handler`).